# ContainerControl Won't Draw Controls On Scroll Properly

Tags: c#, containers

I have a custom `CheckListBox` control that is *supposed* to function the same way as the `CheckedListBox` control but it is not. The problem is when I scroll down, the drawing gets all messed up. The container won't actually scroll down, it will just "jitter" the check boxes around, draw random lines, etc.

Update: I changed the code so the location of each `CheckBox` was set in the `OnControlAdded` method instead of the `OnPaint` method. It now scrolls fine, but the drawing is still messed up! The border is missing, the BackColor changes, the lines for the check boxes are not straight; just a whole mess of things. It works perfectly in the designer (the scrolling and drawing), but not when I run the program.

[image]

Here's the code for the control:

```
public class ChromeCheckListBox : ChromeContainerControl
{
    [Description("Determines what corner(s) will be rounded.")]
    public Utilities.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners Corners { get; set; }

    private int cornerRadius;
    [Description("Determines the radius of the the corners")]
    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get { return cornerRadius; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                Utilities.ThrowError("The radius cannot be less than 1. If you want no radius, set Corners to None.");
            else
                cornerRadius = value;
        }
    }

    [Description("Determines the list of ChromeRadioButton controls that are displayed.")]
    private ChromeCheckBox[] items;
    public ChromeCheckBox[] Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            Controls.Clear();
            Controls.AddRange(items);
        }
    }

    public ChromeCheckListBox()
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Corners = Utilities.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All;
        this.CornerRadius = 1;
        this.Items = new ChromeCheckBox[0];
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);

    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                Items[i].Location = new Point(2 + Padding.Left, 2 + Padding.Top);
            else
                Items[i].Location = new Point(2 + Padding.Left, Items[i - 1].Location.Y + Size.Ceiling(this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(Items[i - 1].Text, Items[i - 1].Font)).Height);
        }
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;
        canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Rectangle region = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
        GraphicsPath path = Utilities.RoundedRectangle.Create(region, CornerRadius, Corners);
        canvas.FillPath(new LinearGradientBrush(region, fillColors[0], fillColors[1], 90), path);
        canvas.DrawPath(new Pen(borderColor), path);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add an invalidate in the scroll event?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Instead of setting the location of the check boxes in the OnPaint method, I should set them in the OnControlAdded method. Also, on the OnScroll method, I need to Invalidate the control causing it to redraw.

So, it should (well maybe not *should*, but could) look like this:

```
public class ChromeCheckListBox : ChromeContainerControl
{
    [Description("Determines what corner(s) will be rounded.")]
    public Utilities.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners Corners { get; set; }

    private int cornerRadius;
    [Description("Determines the radius of the the corners")]
    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get { return cornerRadius; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                Utilities.ThrowError("The radius cannot be less than 1. If you want no radius, set Corners to None.");
            else
                cornerRadius = value;
        }
    }

    [Description("Determines the list of ChromeRadioButton controls that are displayed.")]
    private ChromeCheckBox[] items;
    public ChromeCheckBox[] Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            Controls.Clear();
            Controls.AddRange(items);
        }
    }

    public ChromeCheckListBox()
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Corners = Utilities.RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All;
        this.CornerRadius = 1;
        this.Items = new ChromeCheckBox[0];
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);

    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                Items[i].Location = new Point(2 + Padding.Left, 2 + Padding.Top);
            else
                Items[i].Location = new Point(2 + Padding.Left, Items[i - 1].Location.Y + Size.Ceiling(this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(Items[i - 1].Text, Items[i - 1].Font)).Height);
        }
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
    {
        base.OnScroll(se);
        base.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;
        canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Rectangle region = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
        GraphicsPath path = Utilities.RoundedRectangle.Create(region, CornerRadius, Corners);
        canvas.FillPath(new LinearGradientBrush(region, fillColors[0], fillColors[1], 90), path);
        canvas.DrawPath(new Pen(borderColor), path);
    }
```